Query On Realm Object Doesn't Emit When Embedded Realm Object's parameter is updated
Hello I am using Kotlin Realm as my Database for my Kotlin Multiplatform project.
My Setup
I have the structure of the following two objects:
class MyRealmObject: RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = ""
    var myEmbeddedRealmObjects: RealmList<MyEmbeddedRealmObject> = realmListOf()
}

class MyEmbeddedRealmObject: EmbeddedRealmObject {
    var exampleEmbeddedParam: String = ""
}

Additionally I have a query on my database that looks like this:
fun observeMyRealmObject(id: String): Flow<MyRealmObject?> = realm
    .query<MyRealmObject>("id = $0", id)
    .first()
    .asFlow()
    .mapLatest { myRealmObject: MyRealmObject -> myRealmObject.obj }

The problem
When I now update the exampleEmbeddedParam parameter of any of the MyEmbeddedRealmObject's, no new state update for my Flow gets emitted.
I learned that there is a default limitation of a nested hierarchy of 4 for the .asFlow() function, which I can overcome using the keyPaths parameter for the .asFlow() function.
However, from my perspective, the myEmbeddedRealmObjects is on hierarchy level 1, so the query should be notified when any of the MyEmbeddedRealmObject's exampleEmbeddedParam (level 2) gets updated.
This is, however, not the case and only if I add an explicit keyPaths parameter like  .asFlow(listOf("myEmbeddedRealmObjects.*") or  .asFlow(listOf("*.*") my query emits an update.
Question
Is it per default, that realmList parameters or any other second level EmbeddedRealmObject changes are ignored unless I explicitly use the keyPaths parameters of the .asFlow() function? And how can I overcome this problem besides using explicit keyPath parameters for all queries that needs to get updates from embedded realm object parameters?
Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance

For clarity, can you confirm that the object whose embedded object is being updated is the same one that matches the query? query<MyRealmObject>("id = $0", id)?

Yes that is the case.
An example update could look like the following:
            realm.write {
                val myRealmObject = query<MyRealmObject>("id == $0", myObjectId).find().first()
                findLatest(myRealmObject)?.apply { this.myEmbeddedRealmObjects.first().apply { exampleEmbeddedParam = "test" }}
            }


The issue you're encountering is that when you call .first() after query<>(), it returns a frozen Realm object, which means you're not receiving any updates. To fix this, you should call .asFlow() after the query to get a flow of live, up-to-date data, and then map it according to your needs. Here's how you can modify the code:
fun observeMyRealmObject(id: String): Flow<MyRealmObject?> = realm
    .query<MyRealmObject>("id = $0", id)
    .asFlow() // Convert the result to a flow of live data
    .mapLatest { result ->
        result.list.firstOrNull() // Get the first item from the list
    }

By calling .asFlow() before .first(), you're working with a flow of live data, ensuring you receive updates as the data changes.
Let me know, if you still facing the same issue.
